# Autolisp list manipulation

Tags: list, autolisp

I am struggling with Autolisp and I cannot find the answer I am looking for.

I have an empty list and I am filling it with point coordinates that I have turned into strings. The list that is produced is something like:

> (12.5484,7.6054,0.0000 17.0626,8.1782,0.0000 17.5642,10.7199,0.0000
>   12.0110,11.4716,0.0000)

Is there any possible way that the list filling can be made vertically and have an output something like:

(12.5484,7.6054,0.0000
17.0626,8.1782,0.0000
17.5642,10.7199,0.0000
12.0110,11.4716,0.0000)

The code I am using is:

```
(setq lst()) ;create empty list named lst

    (while
        (setq a (getpoint "\nTick the Point")) ;select points

        (setq x (rtos(car a))) ;get as X the x of a point (as string)
        (setq y (rtos(cadr a))) ;get as Y the y of a point (as string)
        (setq z (rtos(caddr a))) ;get as Z the z of a point (as string)
        (setq pnt (strcat x "," y ","z))

        (setq lst (cons pnt lst)) ;start filling the empty list with the coordinates of the points


    )
```

Comment: A list has no direction, neither horizontal nor vertical.

Comment: I am thinking that I am using list wrong. I could just write the pnt string to a txt file maybe??? I can admit that I am confused.If you can help with that...

Comment: Your question is about a specific solution without telling us what the problem is and why you think this is the correct solution. Please start your question by describing the underlying problem you are trying to solve. I suspect the solution will have nothing to do with formatting a list.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem that you are facing is regarding just the printing of the values that you have stored in the list. The values that are stored are absolutely fine.

So I think you should just add these lines to your existing code (if you want the output as shown above):

1. To write to a text file:

   ```
   (prompt "\n* Text file written to directory of current drawing *")(terpri)
   (setq fname(getstring "\n Enter a valid file name: "))  

   ;if the user doesn't provide a filename, use the drawing name
   (if (= fname "")        
       (setq fname (substr (getvar "dwgname") 1 (- (strlen (getvar "dwgname")) 4)))
   )
   ;open the file
   (setq txt (open (strcat (getvar "dwgprefix") fname ".txt") "w"))

   ;loop to write data to the file
   (foreach item lst
       (write-line item txt)
   )

   ;close the file
   (close txt) 
   (princ (strcat "\n* Text file " (getvar "dwgprefix") fname " has been created *\n"))
   ```
2. To print in the command line (with the starting and ending brackets, as requested):

   ```
   (setq counter 0)
   (princ "\n(")
   (while (> (length lst)  (+ counter 1))
       (progn
           (princ (strcat (nth counter lst) "\n"))     
           (setq counter (1+ counter))
       )
   )
   (princ (strcat (last lst) ")"))
   (princ)
   ```
3. To print in the command line (without any brackets):

   ```
   (terpri)
   (foreach item lst 
       (progn
           (princ item)
           (terpri)
       )
   )
   (princ)
   ```

Let me know if you face any other problem.
BTW: I too am a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(setq ptlist '())
(mapcar '(lambda (pt) 
        (strcat (rtos (car pt)) "," (rtos (cadr pt)) "," (rtos (caddr pt))))
        (reverse (while (setq pttemp(getpoint "Your point:"))
           (if pttemp (cons pttemp ptlist))
        ))
)
```

mapcar expression will return to you a list of strings converted from dots. If you need to convert this list to a string, use the function (apply 'strcat (list-of-strings))

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer @Govinda provided to the question. Changing how the code prints the list can show you what you're looking to achieve.

If you're struggling with in understanding lists, then code below is designed to easily read how the list is being built. The code will print either the nested list or the original list, depending on which one is uncommented under "Return Variable".

```
;; Printing Results via Command Line
(defun C:PrintResults(/ lResults DataPoint)
  
  ;; Calling Function
  (setq lResults (CreateList))
  
  ;; Printing List
  (princ "\n \n")
  (princ "List : ")(princ lResults)
  (princ "\n \n")

  ;; Printing List Contents - New line per data point
  (foreach DataPoint lResults
    (princ DataPoint)(terpri)
  );foreach
  (princ)
);defun C:PrintResults


;; Original
(defun CreateList(/ NestedList MasterList lst a x y z)
    (setq NestedList nil)
    (setq MasterList nil)
    (setq lst nil) ;create empty list named lst

    (while 
        (setq a (getpoint "\nTick the Point")) ;select points
        (terpri)

        (setq x (rtos(car a))) ;get as X the x of a point (as string)
        (setq y (rtos(cadr a))) ;get as Y the y of a point (as string)
        (setq z (rtos(caddr a))) ;get as Z the z of a point (as string)

        ;; A nested list setup
        (setq NestedList (list x y z))
        (setq MasterList (append MasterList (list NestedList)))
        (princ "List 1 : ")(princ MasterList)(terpri)

        ;; Original Setup
        (setq pnt (strcat x "," y ","z))
        (setq lst (cons pnt lst)) ;start filling the empty list with the coordinates of the points
        (princ "List 2 : ")(princ lst)(terpri)
    );while 

  ;; Returned variable
  ;MasterList
  (reverse lst); Making the first entry the first item in the list
);defun EmptyList
```